# Full screen apps on a dual-screen mac

Tags: macos, mac

I've got a mac mini running OS X 10.9.3 right now, but every time I try to full-screen a program (Dota2 for example), or a Youtube video the 2nd screen turns grey and is utterly useless.

I thought that this problem had been addressed by Apple as of 10.9? Is there something I need to configure to get it working so that I can use the 2nd screen with a full-screen app on the 1st, or was I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

It's never been any different. Closest you can get is maximised, rather than fullscreen.

Same on Yosemite, as far as I'm aware.

Why 10.9.3, btw? You're missing out on some security updates.

Comment: Oh, its a work PC that I haven't gotten around to updating. I'm actually getting Yosemite as we speak.

Comment: I've avoided it so far - too many reports of bad experiences on SE (which I am aware is like complaining the doctor's waiting room is full of sick people;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe 10.9 did allow what you're describing. Have you tried just full-screening a Safari window and seeing if the other monitor switches to the gray screen?

My guess is that possibly DOTA and/or YouTube are taking over both screens when you put them in full screen mode. If you're able to make a Safari or Finder window full screen without the second screen graying out, it'd be a good way to tell whether that's the case or not.